# How to get corresponding value of key from two arrays in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, php-7

I have the following arrays in json encode:

```
Array1 {"1":"9","3":"7","4":"6","5":"10","6":"8"}
Array2 {"1":"1","2":"1","3":"1","4":"1","5":"1","6":"7"}
```

Then Json decode and put in print_r()
I got:

```
stdClass Object ( [1] => 9 [3] => 7 [4] => 6 [5] => 10 [6] => 8 )
stdClass Object ( [1] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 7 )
```

Where in Array1 values (9, 7, 6, 10, 8) are product id and Array2 values (1,1,1,1,7) are corresponding product quantity.

Now I would like to fetch products based on products Id and want to show the corresponding quantity.

How can I do this in foreach?

Comment: how can I do this? its already added in your tags, use `foreach`, try it first

Comment: The output of your `print_r` doesn't correspond to your input (the second object has no `2` property).

Comment: Just need for matching keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the `$assoc` parameter to `json_decode` to true, we can convert the JSON values into arrays rather than objects, and then iterate through the `product_id` array, finding matching quantities from the second array:

```
$j1 = '{"1":"9","3":"7","4":"6","5":"10","6":"8"}';
$j2 =  '{"1":"1","2":"1","3":"1","4":"1","5":"1","6":"7"}';
$array1 = json_decode($j1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($j2, true);
foreach ($array1 as $key => $product_id) {
    $quantity = $array2[$key] ?? 0;
    echo "Product $product_id: Quantity: $quantity\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Product 9: Quantity: 1
Product 7: Quantity: 1
Product 6: Quantity: 1
Product 10: Quantity: 1
Product 8: Quantity: 7
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BWvue)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

```
$string1 = '{"1":"9","3":"7","4":"6","5":"10","6":"8"}';
$string2 = '{"1":"1","2":"1","3":"1","4":"1","5":"1","6":"7"}';
$array1 = json_decode($string1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($string2, true);

// Filter arrays to keep only those keys that both have in common
$filtered1 = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);
$filtered2 = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);

// Create new array with $filtered1 as keys and $filtered2 as values
$newArray = array_combine($filtered1, $filtered2);

// Test
$exampleId = 7;
$exampleQuantity = $newArray[$exampleId]; // Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple foraech and a check if the product Id exists :

```
$productId = json_decode('{"1":"9","3":"7","4":"6","5":"10","6":"8"}', true);
$productQuantity = json_decode('{"1":"1","2":"1","3":"1","4":"1","5":"1","6":"7"}', true);

foreach($productId as $id){
  $quantity = "?";  //if id not exists 
  if(array_key_exists($id, $productQuantity)) {
    $quantity = $productQuantity[$id];
  }
  echo "productId: ".$id." Quantity:".$quantity."<br>\n";
}
```

returns

```
productId: 9 Quantity:?
productId: 7 Quantity:?
productId: 6 Quantity:7
productId: 10 Quantity:?
productId: 8 Quantity:?
```

Answer (score -1):

There can be multiple implementation:

You can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) in foreach loop

or you can use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) which return you a new array with product => quantity